# Total bytes allocated on dynamic heap

Tags: c, malloc

Assume `sizeof(int)`.
Then, what's the total size of bytes that will be allocated on the dynamic heap?
And can you please explain why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXROW 8
#define MAXCOL 27

int main()
{
    int (*p)[MAXCOL];
    p = (int (*) [MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW *sizeof(*p));
    return0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the code does?

Comment: Well, I don't really care what it does it's just a question from a quiz...

Comment: Ok, if you don't even care then we don't need to answer.

Comment: What? How did you make this conclusion? I don't need to know what it does further than that function. It just allocates the memory and that's it, and the question is how many bytes were allocated on the heap...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ...

Comment: Hint: the total size allocated from the heap depends on the size of the `int` type and available memory.

Comment: The code does not compile.  You did not even try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume "sizeof(int) is "(what?)... I guess you meant 4.
In the first line you declare p to be a pointer to an array of 27 integers.
In the second line you allocate memory in the heap for size of dereferenced p - which is 27 integers times 8 - that's 27*4*8 so the number of bytes allocated is 864.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
int (*p)[MAXCOL];
```

is eqivalent to saying, declare `p` as  a pointer to an array of `MAXCOL` number of `int`s.

So, considering `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes (32 bit compiler / platform), 
`sizeof(*p)` is 108, and `MAXROW *sizeof(*p)` is `8 * 108`, and [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) allocate that many bytes, if successful.

Also, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @user3741208 What happened when you tried to print `MAXROW *sizeof(*p)` as an integer?

Comment: Lundin, it prints 864

Comment: @user3741208 There you go then. `8 * (27*4)`

Comment: @user3741208 Ok, my bad, I confused `MAXROW` and `MAXCOL`

Comment: doesn't work either... well I guess their computers have weird CPUs, thanks anyway guys!

Comment: the answer is 432, MAXROW*MAXCOL*2

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be `MAXROW*MAXCOL*sizeof(int)`.  The size of `int` cannot be determined from the code shown.  It can be `2`, `4`, `8`... or even `42`, pretty much anything greater than `0`.

If your teacher or course expects `432`, they rely on extra context you failed to provide.  Re-reading your question, you write *assume sizeof(int)*. You need to say what should be assumed precisely.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned it correctly. It's supposed to `sizeof(int)=4`

Comment: Then `MAXROW * MAXCOL * sizeof(int)` = `27 * 8 * 4` = `864`.